# VB.NET Collision oF 2 Graph Rectangles in bitmap

Tags: vb.net, collision-detection

I'm pretty new to programming. I'm trying to code OOP as much as possible .

Problem: How can I detected if two graphics make a collision with each other in a single picturebox?

Now here are the questions:

1. Is there anyway I can do this with graphics on a bitmap. I have seen a lot of examples where two separate picterbox are used to make a collision with each, but how to do this with my example?
2. How can I improve my current code?

   ```
   Public Class RechtHoek

   'property

   Public Property Y As Integer
       Set(value As Integer)
           _y = value
       End Set
       Get
           Return _y
       End Get
   End Property

   Public Property X As Integer
       Set(value As Integer)
           _x = value
       End Set
       Get
           Return _x
       End Get
   End Property

   'Variables

   Dim _y As Integer
   Dim _x As Integer
   Dim _maxY As Integer
   Dim _maxX As Integer   


   'Variabele om kleur te wijzingen
   Dim kleur As Color = RandomKleur()
   Dim VeranderKleur As Boolean = False
   Dim brush2 As New SolidBrush(RandomKleur)


   'variablen om rechthoek te draaien

   'Variabelen voor bewegen van de rechthoeken
   Dim goingUp As Boolean = False
   Dim goingRight As Boolean = False
   'constructor 
   Public Sub New(x As Integer, y As Integer, maxX As Integer, MaxY As Integer)

       _y = y
       _x = x
       _maxX = maxX
       _maxY = MaxY
   End Sub

   Public Sub DrawRechthoekHorizontaal(graph As Graphics)


       Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Black)
       Dim rect As New Rectangle(_x, Y, 40, 100)


       graph.FillRectangle(brush2, rect)
       graph.DrawRectangle(pen, rect)

   End Sub

   Public Sub DrawRechthoekVerticaal(graph As Graphics)


       Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Black)
       Dim rect As New Rectangle(_x, Y, 100, 40)



       graph.FillRectangle(brush2, rect)
       graph.DrawRectangle(pen, rect)

   End Sub  


   Public Function RandomKleur() As Color


       Dim myAlpha As Integer = 0
       Dim myRed As Integer = 0
       Dim myGreen As Integer = 0
       Dim myBlue As Integer = 0

       Randomize()


       myAlpha = CInt(Int((254 * Rnd()) + 0))
       Randomize()
       myGreen = CInt(Int((254 * Rnd()) + 0))
       Randomize()
       myRed = CInt(Int((254 * Rnd()) + 0))
       Randomize()
       myBlue = CInt(Int((254 * Rnd()) + 0))

       'Color.FromArgb(myAlpha, myRed, myGreen, myBlue)

       Return Color.FromArgb(myAlpha, myRed, myGreen, myBlue)


   End Function

   Public Sub Up()
       Y -= 10
   End Sub

   Public Sub Down()
       Y += 10
   End Sub

   Public Sub Right()
       X -= 10
   End Sub

   Public Sub Left()
       X += 10
   End Sub


   Public Sub MoveX()

       If goingRight Then

           Right()

       Else

           Left()
       End If

       If X < 0 Then

           goingRight = False

           'verander van kleur 
           If X = -10 Then
               VeranderKleur = True
               brush2.Color = RandomKleur()
           End If

       ElseIf X > 1600 Then


           goingRight = True

           'verander van kleur 
           If X = 1610 Then
               VeranderKleur = False
               brush2.Color = RandomKleur()
           End If

       End If


   End Sub

   Public Sub MoveY()

       If goingUp Then

           Up()

       Else

           Down()

       End If

       If Y < 0 Then

           goingUp = False

           'verander van kleur 
           If Y = -10 Then
               VeranderKleur = True
               brush2.Color = RandomKleur()
           End If

       ElseIf Y > 900 Then

           goingUp = True

           'verander van kleur 
           If Y = 910 Then
               VeranderKleur = True
               brush2.Color = RandomKleur()
           End If

       End If

   End Sub

   End Class

   Public Class FormBewegendeRechtHoeken

   Dim rectY As RechtHoek
   Dim rectX As RechtHoek

   Dim bitmap As Bitmap

   Private img As Image

   Private Sub FormRechtHoek_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       bitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox.Width, PictureBox.Height)

       'X = plaats waar rechthoek start op x as , Y = plaats waar rechthoekstart op y as 'Max x hoogete &' Max Y hoogte 
       rectY = New RechtHoek(PictureBox.Width \ 2, PictureBox.Height, PictureBox.Width, PictureBox.Height)

       rectX = New RechtHoek(PictureBox.Width, PictureBox.Height \ 2, PictureBox.Width, PictureBox.Height)


       Draw()

       TheTimer.Start()

   End Sub

   Private Sub Botsing()


   End Sub

   Private Sub Draw()

       Using graph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)

           graph.Clear(Color.Yellow)



           rectX.DrawRechthoekHorizontaal(graph)


           'Omkeren van de rechthoek in het midden
           If rectY.Y < 450 Then
               rectY.DrawRechthoekHorizontaal(graph)
           End If

           If rectY.Y > 450 Then

               rectY.DrawRechthoekVerticaal(graph)

           End If



       End Using

       PictureBox.Image = bitmap

   End Sub

   Private Sub TheTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TheTimer.Tick


       rectY.MoveY()
       rectX.MoveX()
       Draw()

   End Sub

   End Class
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the rectangle structures you draw in an array or a list, you can check a collision like this:

The rectangles collide when one rectangle contains at least one edge point of the other rectangle. So you can define a function:

```
Function CheckRectCollision(Rect1 as Rectangle, Rect2 as Rectangle) as Boolean
   If Rect1.Contains(New Point(Rect2.Left, Rect2.Top) Orelse _
      Rect1.Contains(New Point(Rect2.Left, Rect2.Bottom) Orelse _
      Rect1.Contains(New Point(Rect2.Right, Rect2.Top) Orelse _
      Rect1.Contains(New Point(Rect2.Right, Rect2.Bottom) Then
      Return True
    Else
      Return False
    End If
End Function
```

That way you can check if two rectangles collide. Find exclusive permutations for all rectangle pairs you have and call the function for each pair.

Comment: or just `Return Rect1.IntersectsWith(Rect2)`.

Comment: Ok, Lars, you win. But it probably does the same thing anyways ;-)